# Perl RegExp: print lines that matches specific timestamps

Tags: regex, perl

I've got a problem that I'm not sure how to solve. I have a huge log-file with roughly 250k lines, each line of information is seperated by a minute (i.e. 09:00:00, 09:01:00 etc.) Instead of extracting every line that I need in a spreadsheet, I want do to it through a script. Though I'm not that experienced in scripting yet, but I'm trying to learn Perl.

What I want to do is: to extract every line that matches the timestamps (09:03:00, 09:18:00, 09:33:00, 09:48:00) and print it to a new file.

This is my horrible bad attempt in accomplishing this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use diagnostics;

my @expression = ( '09:03:00', '09:18:00', '09:33:00', '09:48:00' );
open FILE, "logfile.txt" or die $!;
if (FILE =~ @expression) {
print "$_\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so:

```
open FILE, "logfile.txt" or die $!;
print grep /09:(03|18|33|48):00/, <FILE>;
close FILE or warn $!;
```

But there's no need for perl, ie:

```
grep '09:\(03\|18\|33\|48\):00' logfile.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, using grep was a better approach I suppose. Again thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You’re not really using a regexp in your code.  The expression you want is rather

```
my $expression = /09:(03|18|33|48):00/
```

And the code for scanning the file probably doesn’t work either.  A more standard way is

```
while(<FILE>)
{
  if(/$expression/) { print; }
}
```

or

```
while(<FILE>)
{
  if($_ =~ $expression)
  {
    print "$_\n";
  }
}
```